# Web Animations API — how to play backwards rather than reverse?

Tags: animation, web-animations, web-animations-api

The Web Animations API has the `reverse` method which allows the running animation to be played back in the opposite direction it is currently headed.

However I have a scenario where I would just like to play a defined animation backwards. At present, I am accomplishing this by checking if the animation is going forwards or backwards first and then doing the opposite but this feels wonky!

Is there an established pattern for just asking a defined animation to run backwards (and not necessarily run in reverse from its current playhead)?

In code example below, if you are on the first instance (`idx === 0`) I check if you are going forwards by checking if `playbackRate` is `1` first. Without this, the animation would run backwards first.

Feels like there should be a simpler way of running an animation backwards when required — is there?

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".thing");
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var span = document.querySelector("span");
const move = box.animate(
    [{ transform: "translate(0px, 0px)" }, { transform: "translate(100px, 0px)" }],
    { duration: 500, fill: "both" }
);
move.pause();

let idx = 0;

function choose() {
    if (idx === 0) {
        move.playbackRate === 1 ? move.play() : move.reverse();
    } else {
        move.reverse();
    }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    choose();
    idx = idx === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    span.textContent = idx;
});
```

```css
.thing {
    width:49px;
    height: 49px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="thing"></div>
<button type="button">ClickMe</button>
<span>0</span>
```

Comment: Isn't reverse the same as backwards? The wording is confusing to me.

Comment: It is confusing!  reverse takes the current position and goes in the opposite direction. Backwards always goes backwards through the keyframes

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the [direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EffectTiming/direction) property, e.g.

```js
move.effect.updateTiming({ direction: 'reverse' });
```